ts(7016) when using vue js 3
I set up my vue js 3 project on vite using npm create vue@latest and I chose TypeScript from the list of dependencies.

Whenever I import a component, the location gets underlined in red in my VS Code. When I hover over, the following message appears: Could not find a declaration file for module './components/ComponentOne.vue'. 'c:/Users/me/.../src/components/ComponentOne.vue' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7016).
I searched for possible answers and the suggested solution was to create a shims-vue.d.ts file (which I didn't have) and include the extension in tsconfig.json. I tried that, however I included the extension in tsconfig.app.json as I do not have tsconfig.json in the project. This did not help.
Also, it sounds weird that I would have to set up TS manually when selecting TS during the project set-up.
The application runs fine, however, the underline in ide is not disappearing. Could someone please explain to me what to do? And why is it happening?
Shall I set up TS manually despite selecting the language at the project set-up? I am using composition API and a SFC.
Thanks!

Do you have a public repo on Github or something?

Is your import a default or named import?

default import, I selected TypeScript, Pinia and Vitest as Yes

In the given screenshot, TS is NOT selected. Same for the rest btw. Text underlined is yes.

@kissu Seems to be taken from the Vue docs: https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html

@DustInComp yeah I mean, I hope OP shared the actual screenshot of the terminal rather than an image from somewhere else...

I started the project already so it is hard to show something already happened. Primarily, I wanted to show the moment when I selected TS.

I recommend starting it again for faster troubleshooting.

As @kissu advised, I started a new project (screenshot updated). When importing the component to app.vue, it still had the same error in VSCode.

Do you have a public repo on Github or something?

I do but I would rather not share that. If an error occurred twice on two independent projects created a couple of weeks apart, it seems to be a rather common occurrence and should be easy to mimic. All I want to know at this point is whether it is an IDE issue or / if something has changed in TS/ vue3 set up as there is no  shims-vue.d.ts file anymore.

I am not asking for a private repo but for a [repro] where we could see the bug reproduced. Might be your IDE or your project, hence why I am trying to narrow it down to see if I could replicate the issue. I don't think that a shims file is mandatory but if you have not changed the code itself there is low chance of it breaking out of the blue. Maybe give the TS server a restart in your VS code.
